# $(this) not working; boolean always false. Not able to add class

Tags: jquery

here is my code below:

```html
<head>
  <title>Dwarka</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dwarka/src/main/resources/css/restaurantstyles.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#somebutton').click(function(event) {
        var name = $('#userName').val();
        $.post('FirstServlet', {
          userName: 'name'
        }, function(responseText) {
          $('#somediv').text(responseText);
        });
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(this).click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().hasClass('active'));
        $('#tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a id="tab" href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a id="tab" class="active" href="#home"><span id="tab">Home</span></a>
      <a id="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a id="tab" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
  <div id="somediv"> </div>
</body>
```

I want to dynamically change the color of selected tab.
`alert($(this).parent().hasClass('active'));` is always giving a false value. 
 `$('#tab').removeClass('active');` is not removing the class.
`$(this).addClass('active');` is not able to add the class.

Comment: what are you expecting from the `$(this).click(` inside the `$(document).ready` to do? Where do you think that handler is bound to ?

Comment: You can only use any given `id` **once** in a document. `this` in your second `document.ready` is `document`.

Comment: I am new to jquery. i want to remove and add class dynamically.

Comment: I think this may be related to "scope" -- is `$(this)` referring to the same thing where it is first invoked, and then inside of the click handler?

Comment: Instead of `alert($(this).parent().hasClass('active'));` do `alert($(this));` so you see what in that case `this` is.

Comment: also, don't use $(document).ready() twice, just use one an inside put all your code.

Comment: `alert($(this));` it prints object.

Comment: Don't use `alert` to debug. Use developer tools and `console.log()`.

Comment: And first, fix the id problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's the use of `$('#somebutton').click()` handler in your example... But I left it there to show you how to use only one `$(document).ready()`.

All `id` must be unique. A class can be used multiple places.

`$(this)` represent different element depending on the context where it is used. In the `$(document).ready()`, it represents the `document`. In a click handler, it represents the clicked element. In an `.each()` loop, it represents the element of the current collection iteration.

So be careful with `$(this)`.

So finally... On click, it's just about to add/remove an `active` class to change the color:

1. Remove the `active` class from all the `.tab` elements.
2. Add it to the clicked element

```css
.active{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Dwarka</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dwarka/src/main/resources/css/restaurantstyles.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      $('#somebutton').click(function(event) {
        var name = $('#userName').val();
        $.post('FirstServlet', {
          userName: 'name'
        }, function(responseText) {
          $('#somediv').text(responseText);
        });
      });
    
      $(".tab").click(function() {
        // Remove the active class from all .tab elements.
        $(".tab").removeClass("active");

        // Add the active class to the clicked element.
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Use console.log() instead of alert() to debug your scripts ;)
        console.log($(this).hasClass('active'));
      });
      
    });  // End ready
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a  class="tab logo" href="#default">CompanyLogo</a>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a class="tab active" href="#home"><span id="tab">Home</span></a>
      <a class="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a class="tab" href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
  <div id="somediv"> </div>
</body>
```